# How to open a file with tramp mode when Helm is active?

Tags: helm, tramp

I recently started using Helm with the configuration below

```
(require 'helm-config)
(helm-mode 1)
(define-key global-map [remap occur] 'helm-occur)
(define-key global-map [remap list-buffers] 'helm-buffers-list)
(define-key global-map [remap dabbrev-expand] 'helm-dabbrev)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
(setq helm-M-x-fuzzy-match t)
```

Today I figured out that Tramp mode doesn't work anymore. When I try to open a file with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> and enter `/sudo:root@`<kbd>TAB</kbd> nothing happens. Usually I'd expect that `localhost` is substituted and tramp asks for a password.

How can I have a still functional tramp mode plus a working Helm?

Comment: Isn't `root` and `localhost` default for `/sudo`? I think `/sudo::` should work.

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Good, question. I'm going through this right now on 2020.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the way it works for me is the following:

1. call helm-find-files (usually <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>)
2. write `/scp:`
3. if you have used tramp before you get a list with previous locations
   which you can select with <kbd>C-j</kbd> (or type a new remote by hand), pressing now <kbd>C-j</kbd> a second  time or typing a <kbd>:</kbd> will connect you to the remote server
4. now helm completion on the remote starts, type <kbd>/</kbd> if you want to be located in the root directory or <kbd>~</kbd>, if you want to access your home directory

Comment: This does not work for me. Even more when I have a specific port on my virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is an issue and it's odd Helm doesn't recognize the `/ssh:` as usual Emacs does with Tramp.

The way I worked around this is as follows.

With Helm you rewrite the `C-x C-f` command to use `helm-find-files`. What I did then is to remap this to another keybinding, one that is not in use. For instance, in my .emacs I did:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-h") #'helm-find-files)`
```

I bound `helm-find-files` to `C-x c-h` whenever I want to use the helm files finder. Then with the usual `C-x C-f` I keep connecting with the remote servers or vm's using Tramp.

And the nice thing about this is that after you connect with Tramp, then using the `helm-find-files` works ok with the ssh remote connection.

Edit (another option):

Another option, and it's one I ended up doing is to remap the Emacs Elisp function `find-file`, usually bound to `C-x C-f` to a different keybinding, like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-h") 'find-file)
```

And then the `C-x C-f` can be used by Helm with helm-find-file.